# parse json file in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sbjson

i have this json link  [Json_link](http://www.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_14&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%222012-07-29%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22all%22%7D&action=showMatches&params=%7B%22competition_id%22%3A366%7D)

how i can get the (17 : 00) and (Amberg) and (Aubstadt) values. and thanks in advance.

Comment: The JSON data mainly contains HTML data. And the values you're interested are in a in the HTML data. That'll be fun to extract...

Comment: As the comment already says - The data you want is in the html embedded in the JSON. You'll just have to get this and either use a regex or (preferably)an xml parser to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a JSON library into your project and put code at parsing file

```
NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"commands"];
[responseString release];

NSLog(@"%@",[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"parameters"] objectForKey:@"container"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"parameters"] objectForKey:@"content"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"parameters"] objectForKey:@"position"]);



NSLog(@"%@",[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"parameters"] objectForKey:@"params"] objectForKey:@"date"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"parameters"] objectForKey:@"params"] objectForKey:@"display"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"parameters"] objectForKey:@"params"] objectForKey:@"timestamp"]);
```